# problem computing block inverse of factorized matix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm running into trouble when verifying the inverse of the following block matrix using the Schur complement:

My matrix is given by:

$$K = USU^T,$$

where U are its eigenvectors and S the corresponding eigenvalues. Say I'd like to partition the eigenvectors in U and write the resulting matrix in block structure, I get:

$$
\begin{align*}
K = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
K_{11} & K_{12} \\
K_{21} & K_{22} 
\end{array}\right]
&=
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
U_1 S U_1^T & U_1 S U_2^T \\
(U_1 S U_2^T)^T & U_2 S U_2^T 
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
$$

Clearly, the inverse is given by $K^{-1} = US^{-1}U^T$, or in block form:

$$
\begin{align*}
K^{-1} = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
A_{11} & A_{12} \\
A_{21} & A_{22} 
\end{array}\right]
&=
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
U_1 S^{-1} U_1^T & U_1 S^{-1} U_2^T \\
(U_1 S^{-1} U_2^T)^T & U_2 S^{-1} U_2^T 
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
$$

Now, I'd like to verify this using the block inverse, which states:

$$
\begin{align*}
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
A & B \\
C & D 
\end{array}\right]^{-1}&=
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
M & -MBD^{-1} \\
-D^{-1}CM & D^{-1} + D^{-1}CMBD{-1} 
\end{array}\right],
\end{align*}
$$

where $M = (A-BD^{-1}C)^{-1}$ ($M^{-1}$ is known as the Schur complement).

From above, I would expect $M = U_1 S^{-1} U_1^T$, so I'd like to verify this using the Block Inverse:

$$
\begin{align*}
K^{-1}_{1,1} = M &= (U_1SU_1^T - U_1SU_2^T(U_2SU_2^T)^{-1}U_2SU_1^T)^{-1}\\
                 &= (U_1SU_1^T - U_1SU_2^TU_2S^{-1}U_2^TU_2SU_1^T)^{-1} \\
                 &= (U_1SU_1^T - U_1SIS^{-1}ISU_1^T)^{-1} \\
                 &= (U_1SU_1^T - U_1SU_1^T)^{-1} \\
                 &= 0,
\end{align*}
$$

which is in disagreement with my expectation. I went through the above several time but can't figure out where the error lies. Any ideas?

Comment: you are treating $U_1$ and $U_2$ as unitary

Comment: Care to elaborate? I'm exploiting that $U_1^TU_1 = I$ and $U_2U_2^T = I$.

Comment: if you decompose $U$ into blocks you need four blocks, $U=\{\{B_1,B_2\},\{B_3,B_4\}\}$; none of the four blocks $B_n$ is unitary.

Comment: I decomposed $U$ into two blocks, resulting in four blocks for $K$: $$\begin{align*}
U = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
U_{1} \\
U_{2} 
\end{array}\right]\end{align*}$$

Comment: ask yourself what are the dimensions of $S$, $U$, $U_1$ and $U_2$, and you'll see your decomposition is not possible

Comment: ok, I'll indicate dimensions using a tuple (rows,cols): $S = (n,n)$ , $U = (n,n)$, $U_1 = (k,n)$, $U_2 = (n-k, n)$. We get $$
\begin{align*}
K = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
U_{1} \\
U_{2}  
\end{array}\right] S \left[
\begin{array}{c}
U_{1} \\
U_{2}  
\end{array}\right]^T\end{align*}$$, which should all work out (e.g. $U_1 S$ = (k,n)x(n,n) --> (k,n), etc. Any objections to this?

Comment: then $U_1 U_1^T=1$, but you need $U_1^T U_1 =1$, which it's not.